# typescript tricky grammar in mixins

Tags: typescript, class, mixins

```
type Constructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

function f1<T extends {}>(naked: Constructor<T>): any {
    return class dressed extends naked { } // error
}

function f2<T extends Constructor<{}>>(naked: T): any {
    return class dressed extends naked { } // ok
}
```

`f1` says `'dressed' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'.`

i don't think there is any semantic fault in `f1`, but why there is a grammar fault?

Comment: You have it backwards. The error is semantic, not grammatical.

Answer (score 0):

What is confusing is the `Constructor<T>` type because, indeedn we can never specify its generic argument `T` in the class mixin syntax.

With a simpler/non generic definition, we can naturally choose to write a class mixin like `f2`:

```
type Constructor = new (...args: any[]) => any;

function Dressed<T extends Constructor>(Base: T) { // Note: no `: any` return type so that the type inference works.
  return class extends Base {}
}
```

If we need elsewhere a generic `Constructor` type, we can still specify a default type to keep writing `<T extends Constructor>` which is les misleading:

```
type Constructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;
```